# Loading whole input line to program

Tags: c++, getline

I have to load few input lines to my program, but I don't know why it doesn't works for me :(

```
int n;
    string count;
    int *tab = new int[256];
    cin >> n;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        getline(cin, count);
        cin.ignore();
        for (int x = 0; x < count.size(); x++)
            if(count[x]!=' ')tab[(int)count[x]]++;
    }
```

This is what I've already got, the program has to read number of lines to load, then load line, and count every letter, and do it for `n` lines.
It freezes when I type the last line of input, I tried getline without cin.ignore() but it was same.

Comment: What *does* it do? And what's wrong with it?

Comment: You're ignoring the first character of every line but the first.

Comment: What exactly is not working for you? Please also update your post with something which is valid and compiling example.

Comment: Everything compiles, and runs ok, but it stucks while loading input, e.g. I type:
2
Hello World
hello world
and it stucks, nothing happens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"e.g. I type: 2 Hello World hello world and it stucks"

How do you type it? There has to be a newline beween every word, if not, this is only one line so the program still waits for the second line (because you entered 2).

If you want the spaces to be the delimiters, just replace `getline(cin, count);` by `cin >> count;` and let `cin.ignore();` away in *every* case (see chris comment).

Comment: I type 2, then new line, first line to load, new line, second line to load, I tried adding CTRL+Z to end the input, and it still doesn't help.

Comment: @encoree1337 try to put one `cin.ignore()` after `cin >> n` (out of the loop), and remove the `cin.ignore()` from inside the loop. And by the way: you type the new line as pressing RETURN or as some character, e.g. "\n"?

Comment: I made new lines by enter, and I also tried loading from input file, but the ignore after `cin>>n` helped, thanks! :D